# Select only shows last name

Tags: php, forms

I have a form where you need to be able to select the mentor, and add a name. The selecting a mentor is working fine, apart from one part: It only shows the last name ('achternaam') and it needs to show the first name ('voornaam') too. What did I do wrong?

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
            <p>
              <label for="mentor">Mentor:</label>
              <select name="mentor" id="mentor">
                <?php

                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                  //output data of each row
                  while ($mentors = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo '<option value="' . $$mentors['voornaam'] . '">' . $mentors['achternaam'] . '</option>';
                  }
                } else {
                  echo "0 results";
                }

                ?>
              </select> <br>

              <label for="klasnaam">Klasnaam:</label>
              <input type="text" id="klasnaam" name="klasnaam"> <br>
              <input type="hidden" name="action" value="addClass" />
              <input type="submit" value="Submit">

                <?php 
              
                
                ?>
                
            </p> 
          </form>
```

Comment: You only put the last name between the `<option>` and `</option>` tags, so of course that's what it shows. (And I am guessing you want the full name not only to be displayed, but also be _submitted_? Then you need to modify the content of the value attribute as well, because currently in that one, you only put the _first_ name.)

Comment: (And `$$mentors['voornaam']` is also wrong, that needs to be a single `$` only, not two.)

Comment: Sidenote: you shouldn't use the first name of a person (`voornaam`) as the value for the option as well, these are definitely not unique, you should use something unique like an (auto-incremented) id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<option>` element displays what is written between the opening and closing tag. In your current version you only write the last name between the tags.

To fix this, add the first name:

```php
echo '<option value="' . $mentors['voornaam'] . '">' . $mentors['voornaam'] . ' ' . $mentors['achternaam'] . '</option>';
```

The value attribute is not used for displaying. It is the representation of the data when submitting the form.

Note that I also changed `$$mentors['voornaam']` to `$mentors['voornaam']`. There was a `$` too much.

Comment: You might want to also fix the `$$` issue in there